# Checking for a string within a string, and not in another string using SQL

Tags: sql, string, compare, product

I am trying to build a short SQL script that will check if @NewProductAdded is somewhere in @NewTotalProducts. And also if @NewProductAdded is NOT in @OldTotalProducts. Please have a look at the setup below (The real data is in tables, not variables, but a simple example is all I need):

```
declare @NewProductAdded as varchar(max)
declare @NewTotalProducts as varchar(max)
declare @OldTotalProducts as varchar(max)

set @NewProductAdded ='ProductB'
set @NewTotalProducts = 'ProductAProductBProductC'
set @OldTotalProducts = 'ProductAProductC'

SELECT CustomerID FROM Products WHERE NewProductAdded ...
```

I want to make sure that 'ProductB' is contained somewhere within @NewTotalProducts, and is NOT contained anywhere within @OldTotalProducts. Product names vary vastly with thousands of combinations, and there is no way to really separate them from each other in a string. I am sure there is a simple solution or function for this, I just don't know it yet.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using (SQL Server, MySQL, etc.)?

Comment: [tsql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181984.aspx) [mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_position)

Comment: WHERE CHARINDEX(@NewProductAdded, @NewTotalProducts) > 0 AND CHARINDEX(@NewProductAdded, @OldTotalProducts) = 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The specific answer to your question is `like` (or `charindex()` if you are using SQL Server or Sybase):

```
where @NewTotalProducts like '%'+@NewProductAdded+'%' and
      @OldTotalProducts not like '%'+@NewProductAdded+'%'
```

First comment.  If you *have to* use lists stored in strings, at least use delimiters:

```
where ','+@NewTotalProducts+',' like '%,'+@NewProductAdded+',%' and
      ','+@OldTotalProducts+',' not like '%,'+@NewProductAdded+',%'
```

Second comment.  Don't store lists in strings.  Instead, use a temporary tables or table variable:

```
declare @NewTotalProducts table (name varchar(255));

insert into @NewTotalProducts(name)
    select 'ProductA' union all
    select 'ProductB' . . .
```

Note: throughout this answer I have used SQL Server syntax.  The code appears to be SQL Server.

Comment: Thank you, this confirms what I originally thought I should use, the LIKE comparison. But I didn't know variables or table columns could be nested within like your example. And yes, trust me I don't like the lists in the strings but our client uses an older system and that's how we have to handle it. Your example helps very much, thank you!